# Segmentation fault with -O2 in Fortran

Tags: linux, debugging, optimization, segmentation-fault, fortran

While developing a large Fortran software I have now and again come across this error, in particular when compiling with -O2 to have a bit better performance.

In some cases the error is real and can be corrected but in other cases I find no error and assume it is caused by -O2 shuffling around the code. As my old fashioned debugging technique is to add write statements close to the point where the error occurs have I found the error often disappeared when I did that.

Maybe because the -O2 optimization is a bit careful shuffling around such statements.

Recently I had this error in a loop which was not very complex and not very time critical and adding a write statement inside the loop prevented this error.  When I removed the write statement the error came back.  To avoid creating a lot of meaningless output while running the program I found it was sufficient to write to an internal character so for a user nothing changed.

There was no error when compiling the code without -O2 but the loop is inside a module using many local variables and I do not know how to compile one subroutine in a module separately without -O2.

I am using GNU Fortran 7.2.0 on Linux and Windows (this recent error occurred only on Linux but previously I have had similar problems with Windows).  I do not have access to any other compilers but my code is free and has been compiled with other compilers with no problems reported.

So my question is if one can turn off -O2 for a small part of the code inside a module or if there are better alternatives than adding write statements to prevent -O2 to shuffle around the code inside a particular subroutine.

Comment: You have tried compiling and running the code with -fcheck=all -g -fbacktrace ?

Comment: With these symptoms there's a high probability that the code has an out of bounds-array reference. Can you reduce the code to something you can show here and still exhibits the behavior, or else provide a link to the complete code (since you say it is free) and indicate where you think the problem is?

Comment: Would I be correct to sum up your question as: *What compiler tricks can I employ to cover up a problem in my program ?*

Comment: The code (with my bug fix) is on github.com, repository sundmanbo/opencalphad.  It is some 30000 lines of code, some parts quite messy but the error occurs in a specific subroutine.  If I add -g in the compilation the error disappears.  Yes, my question also indicated a way to handle this problem which I think can be useful in other cases.

Comment: But what happens if you compile with -fcheck=all?

Comment: Very interesting, what does -fcheck=all do?  When I add that (together with -O2 and -fopenmp) and at the same time remove my "debug" output there is no segmentation fault.  The segmentation fault reappears if I remove -fcheck=all.  There is no messages from the compilation itself.

Comment: A question is of course does -fcheck=all disable the -O2 so my code is slower?

Comment: Bosse, it doesn't disable optimization, but it does insert a number of runtime checks which can change the code which the compiler emits, and those checks are not zero cost. So the resulting code will be slower, but not as slow as unoptimized code. But correctness over performance and all that....

Comment: My opinion is that the code is correct, it is -O2 that creates a mess.  My dummy write statement has a negligible influence on the speed of one routine which is not important whereas -fcheck=all will have an effect everywhere.  I am very impressed by the work of the compiler constructors but I would like a possibility to turn off -O2 in a specific routine.  Something a preprocessor could do maybe?

Comment: Compilation options apply to whole compilation units, so files or modules in Fortran. (In gfortran at least) the only way you can selectively apply compilation options is to put the code in question in its own file and compile it separately with its own options

Comment: The intent of compiling with -fcheck=all is not to use it in a release version, but to use it during testing to help locate any coding errors. Your conclusion that the code is correct and the segmentation error is caused by the compiler optimization might be true, but it would be the last option I would consider after having definitively ruled out any issues with the code.

Comment: I compiled your code with  FCOPT=  -O1 -g -Wmaybe-uninitialized -fcheck=all , and I get a lot of maybeunitialized warnings. I think you should check those warnings because uninitialized variables can trigger different execution errors depending on the optimization. Note the use of O1, some checks regarding uninitialized values are performed during the optimization phase.

Comment: If you are still having crashes after addressing the maybeuninitialized warnings, you may also want to consider using the electric fence library when compiling.  I haven't used this library in Windows, only Linux, so I'm not sure if it is available.  Just add `-lefence` to your flags.  It will cause your code to crash any time it attempts to read outside of allocated memory and is particularly helpful when passing allocated arrays to functions/subroutines.

Comment: I have run the case which cause the error with valgrind without any warnings but I am aware there may be many uninitialized variables in the code, my programming style is not very strict. Thanks for the tip about -Wmaybe-uninitialized, I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

I arrived here via a web search, and in case it helps anyone, I want to share the solution in my case.  Many commenters have mentioned the possibility of uninitialized variables.  I had no such warning in my code, but I produced an apparently identical effect by allocating storage in a subroutine in such a way that the compiler presumably did not realize that freshly allocated memory was about to be used in the next line.

I did this by accidentally including an allocatable array in a module and then also passing it as an argument to a subroutine that first did the allocation (using the name in the module) and immediately thereafter started assigning values to array elements using the name that I had passed in as an argument.  When I moved from -O1 to -O2, it stopped working.  Rather than detecting the problem, -fcheck=bounds actually caused the code to run without the segfault.

I located the offending line by using -O2 -g -traceback without checking bounds.  When I started referring to the array consistently using the name that I had passed as an argument, the problem went away.

Comment: That is an interesting observation.  I will test this compiling option with my code although I currently does not have this problem.